# Unrequired file created when breaking from an if else statement in Excel Impot

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using C# VS2005 and SQL Server 2005.

I have an Excel import function for my web application.

The import works perfectly if the file chosen by user is correct, and I have made an if-else statement to check for the file content type, and `return;` if the file type is incorrect.

However, whenever the page breaks out of the function, an unrequired file is created in my directory `C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\MP\UploadFiles`.

In my code, it should break out the function and **no file should be created in situations where the check for filetype fails.**

I have tried to troubleshoot the code but to no avail.

---

A sample filename of the unrequired file created is the logged in user name follow by the date time.

E.g. Filename: *admin0120111228113732*, which I do not see how it is created in my following code.

---

I need help in identifying the problem.

Below is my code snippet:

```
if (FileImport.HasFile)
        {
            string loginuser = (User.Identity.Name);
            SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection("DataSource");
            SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();

            // Get the name of the Excel spreadsheet to upload. 
            string strFileName = Server.HtmlEncode(FileImport.FileName);

            // Get the extension of the Excel spreadsheet. 
            string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

            // Validate the file extension. 
            if (strExtension != ".xls" && strExtension != ".xlsx" && strExtension != ".csv")
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Error: Invalid Excel file');</script>");
                return;  //***UNREQUIRED FILE IS CREATED HERE***
            }
            if (strExtension == ".xls" || strExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
                    // Generate the file name to save. 
                    string strUploadFileName = "C:/Documents and Settings/admin/My Documents/Visual Studio 2005/WebSites/MP/UploadFiles/" + loginuser + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;

                    // Save the Excel spreadsheet on server. 
                    FileImport.SaveAs(strUploadFileName);

                    // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
                    string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strUploadFileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

                    using (OleDbConnection connection =
                                 new OleDbConnection(connStr))
                    {
                        string selectStmt = string.Format("Select [Columns] FROM [Sheet1$]");

                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectStmt, connection);

                        connection.Open();
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened");

                        // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
                        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            // SQL Server Connection String
                            string sqlConnectionString = "DataSource";

                            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
                            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                                       new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                            {
                                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserDB";
                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);

                            }
                        }
                    } File.Delete(@strUploadFileName);
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What method is this function called from?  My guess is that the file is being created from the calling method.  Also:  What happens when you change the 3rd if statement into an else if statement?  (the strExtension == ".xls" line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should save the file regardless of the extension, wrap the processing in a try/finally statement, and always delete the saved file in the finally block.

**Update**

There are apparently at least 3 people that don't understand proper programming practices as well as they should.

The purpose of the try/finally is to ensure that the file is deleted under any circumstance since the OP is clearly concerned about stranded files.

And there is absolutely no extra save of the file; the file is already on the web server. SaveAs simply moves the file from the default IIS upload location to a known location so that it can be deleted, again resolving the OPs concern about stranded files.

It is inattention to details like these that lead to a majority of programming problems.

Here is an example of how it should be rewritten:

```
       try {
           // Generate the file name to save. 
           string strUploadFileName = "C:/Documents and Settings/admin/My Documents/Visual Studio 2005/WebSites/MP/UploadFiles/" + loginuser + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;

           // Save the Excel spreadsheet on server. 
           FileImport.SaveAs(strUploadFileName);

       // Validate the file extension. 
        if (strExtension != ".xls" && strExtension != ".xlsx" && strExtension != ".csv")
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Error: Invalid Excel file');</script>");
            return;  //***UNREQUIRED FILE IS CREATED HERE***
        }
        if (strExtension == ".xls" || strExtension == ".xlsx")
        {
                // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
                string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strUploadFileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

                using (OleDbConnection connection =
                             new OleDbConnection(connStr))
                {
                    string selectStmt = string.Format("Select [Columns] FROM [Sheet1$]");

                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectStmt, connection);

                    connection.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened");

                    // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
                    using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        // SQL Server Connection String
                        string sqlConnectionString = "DataSource";

                        // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
                        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                                   new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                        {
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserDB";
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);

                        }
                    }
                }
          } finally {
              File.Delete(@strUploadFileName);
          }
```

Comment: Saving an unneeded file only to delete it afterwards is a misuse of Try/Catch IMO.  It should be there to catch errors and then clean up afterwards.  Not to tip-toe around an error by ignoring it.  Isn't it also possible for File.Delete to cause an exception too?

Comment: @DalinSeivewright: It's not try/catch, it's try/finally to ensure that the file is deleted under any circumstance. And there is absolutely no extra save of the file, it is just moving the file from the default IIS upload file to a known location so that it can be deleted. It is inattention to details like these that lead to a majority of programming problems.